# jQuery Submit will not submit form

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have a for that I am submitting with this button:

```
<button id="registerButton" type="submit" name="submit" style="margin-left: 300px;">Click to Complete</button>
```

I am doing error checking with this jQuery:

```
$('#registerButton').bind('click',function(){
    if($('#formElem').data('errors')){
            alert('Please correct the errors in the Form');
            return false;
        }
});
```

When I go to submit the form it will pop up with the alert if there are errors detected on the form.  However, if there are no errors the button doesn't do anything.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the validation on the submit event of the form.

```
$("#formid").submit(function(e) { 
    if($(this).data('errors')){
        //display error
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the submit
    } else {
       //do something or nothing
       //but it will submit the form
    }

});
```

Comment: Should #form-element be the ID of the submit button or the ID of the form?

Comment: Unfortunately this was promising, however it did not work to submit the form either.  Is there tool that I can use to see where the error is occuring when I click the submit button and there are no errors?

Comment: Firebug for Firefox will show you any JS errors that are occurring.

Comment: @Prine, like SickHipple said, you can view the bugs using firebug addon on firebug. And my code does not contain any errors, so the error is somewhere else. Try to make a demo or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: OMG Thank you!! You led me in the right direction!! There was some javascript email validation that was loose in my code... Firebug popped up and informed me of that... so Thank you it works perfectly now with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add an `else {return true;}` to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide you with a complete minimal example that works for me, in firefox, internet explorer, chrome and opera. Hope that helps.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $("#frm").submit(function(e){

            if($(this).data("errors")){
                alert("errors");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm" action="#sent" data-errors="have errors">
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```